# generating multiple executables from the same sources

Tags: makefile

To build multiple executables from the same source, I have to translate every source file with different Compiler Switches. For every variant, I have a set of defines to be set. I want to store the resulting object files into different subfolders. I have a variable, keeping all object file from all variants. Now I have problems to define a proper static rule to build the object files from the sources:

```
SOURCEEXT=.c
ALL_OBJECT_FILES := abcdefg/cctalkio.o tollcoll/cctalkio.o
source-from-object = $(addsuffix $(SOURCEEXT),$(basename $(notdir $(1))))

$(ALL_OBJECT_FILES): %.o: $(call source-from-object,%.o)
    @echo $*.o
```

when I run `make abcdefg/cctalkio.o`, I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'abcdefg/cctalkio.c', needed by 'abcdefg/cctalkio.o'.  Schluss.
```

The same, when I simpify the rule to:

```
abcdefg/cctalkio.o: %.o: $(call source-from-object,%.o)
    @echo $*.o
```

But when I change the rule to:

```
abcdefg/cctalkio.o: %.o: $(call source-from-object,abcdefg/cctalkio.o)
    @echo $*.o
```

I get `abcdefg/cctalkio.o` as Output. So the stem seems to be `abcdefg/cctalkio`, thus `%.o` should be the same as `abcdefg/cctalkio.o`. But why is make behaving different in both cases?

When I "debug" the source-from-object function:

```
debug:
    @echo $(call source-from-object,/abcdefg/cctalkio.o)
```

I get the expected result `cctalkio.c`, so it seem like the function is working.

Comment: Stick an `$(info source-from-object argument: $1)` to the start of one of the lines in your source-from-object function to see what I am talking about in my answer.

Comment: Nice, I got `%.o` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$(call)` in the prereq is happening immediately and so your function is actually being passed %.o (not the matched result as you expected).

You would have to use something like:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
abcdefg/cctalkio.o: %.o: $$(call source-from-object,%.o)
        ...
```

to get what you want I believe.

Alternatively you could probably loop over your object files and statically give them the correct prerequisites and just let the static pattern rule supply the body.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem. I think I got it. Your solutions doesn't work for me out of the box, but `$(ALL_OBJECT_FILES): %.o: $(call source-from-object,$(%.o))` seems to do the trick :-) (even without the .SECONDEXPANSION)

Comment: What about my solution doesn't work? I don't know that I see how yours can be working but if you say it does then sure. What make are you using for this?

Comment: With your solution, I get `*** No rule to make target `$(call)', needed by `tollcoll/cctalkio.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: Paste the modified makefile you were testing with? Also what does the info debugging from my comment above say with your working solution (try warning instead of info for line numbers)?

Comment: The `$(call)` in my first sentence was a shorthand, not literal. The main block was my solution.

Comment: Your right, your solution is working, I've missed to define the SOURCEEXT variable from the example above (I've moved from the office to my place). Thank you very much! :-)